# I want to combine a concatenation of two lists

Tags: r, combinations, combinatorics, string-concatenation

I need to create a Vector combining the numbers `c(1:10)` and the Terms `c("-KM","-COX")`, so that it would turn out like this:

```
c("1-KM", "1-COX", "2-KM", "2-COX", "3-KM", "3-COX", ...)
```

I have tried using expand.grid to do that, however it returns a data frame, and I would need it to return  a vector. Any help in how I could do that?

Comment: `c(t(outer(1:10, c("-KM","-COX"), paste0)))`

Answer (score 1):

Try this version:

```
apply(expand.grid(v1, v2), 1, function(x) trimws(paste0(x[1], x[2])))

 [1] "1-KM"   "2-KM"   "3-KM"   "4-KM"   "5-KM"   "6-KM"   "7-KM"   "8-KM"  
 [9] "9-KM"   "10-KM"  "1-COX"  "2-COX"  "3-COX"  "4-COX"  "5-COX"  "6-COX" 
[17] "7-COX"  "8-COX"  "9-COX"  "10-COX"
```

**Data:**

```
v1 <- c(1:10)
v2 <- c("-KM", "-COX")
```

Answer (score 1):

After `expand.grid` you can use `paste` to get a `vector` from the returned `data.frame`.

```
do.call(paste0, expand.grid(1:10, c("-KM","-COX")))
# [1] "1-KM"   "2-KM"   "3-KM"   "4-KM"   "5-KM"   "6-KM"   "7-KM"   "8-KM"  
# [9] "9-KM"   "10-KM"  "1-COX"  "2-COX"  "3-COX"  "4-COX"  "5-COX"  "6-COX" 
#[17] "7-COX"  "8-COX"  "9-COX"  "10-COX"
```